# Как вывести результат в div с классом в jquery через функцию tofixed()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть курс валют к ним нужно применить tofixed что бы было так 65.42 руб а не такой результат 65.42849560873613 не понимаю как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку Показать курс результат записывался в `<div class="rubusd">тут должен быть результат</div>`

```
<div class="monitoring-currency">
    <div class="rubusd"></div>
    <div class="rubeur"></div>
    <button class="showcourse">Показать курс</button>
```

```
$(function(){
    $('.showcourse').click(function(){
        $.get('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest',
        {'access_key': '0404df422cd3b27ef29d6013ff2459b9', 'base' : 'EUR'},
        function(response){
            $('.rubusd').text('USD' + ' ' + response.rates.RUB/response.rates.USD + ' ' + 'RUB');
            $('.rubeur').text('EUR' + ' ' + response.rates.RUB + ' ' + 'RUB');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `response.rates.RUB` — это и есть полученное число? Ну вот `response.rates.RUB.toFixed(2)`

Comment: да написал я к вы мне подсказали не получилось пропал курс рубля к евро

Comment: Наверно оно записано в виде строки, а не числа. Тогда надо его преобразовать в число, потом только использовать fixed. Или `Number(response.rates.RUB).toFixed(2)` или `(+response.rates.RUB).toFixed(2)` - - Плюсик перед строкой также преобразует её в число, как и Number

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за помощь мне помогла функция + Number(response.rates.RUB).toFixed(2) уже 3 день ломал голову как это сделать а оказалось все очень просто большое вам спасибо